# Conditional class based on service property in Angular 5

Tags: angular, components

I have a simple Angular 5 application that needs to have a continuous audio player. It currently consists of a component that lists audio files, a component that contains an audio player, and an audioplayer service that actually plays the files.

When the user clicks one of the tracks, the audioplayer service starts playing this track using the wavesurfer.js library, inside a `#waveform` div that sits inside the audioplayer component. This is handled by a public object `wavesurfer` inside the service. This object emits an event when the track is done playing. I have a few divs (buttons and indicators) in the audioplayer template that I want to change classes depending on whether the track is finished playing or not.

I tried to add the following code to the component:

```
this.audioPlayerService.wavesurfer.on('finish', function () {
   alert('works');
});
```

But this does not work. I tried to follow some other examples that I found online, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to communicate between the service and the component. Most things I find speak about Angular 2 anyway, so I'm not sure if it doesn't work because I'm doing it wrong, or because it's a different version. How can I watch for the finish event in the audio player component, or how can I watch for changes in the public variable playing?

Here is the code in the service:

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer';

@Injectable()
export class AudioPlayerService {

  public wavesurfer: WaveSurfer;
  public playing = false;

  constructor() { }

  setTrack(track): void {
      const that = this;

      // create a new instance
      this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: '#waveform'
      });

      // fire the play function
      this.wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
          that.play();
      });

      // load the waveform
      this.wavesurfer.load(track.preview_url);

      this.wavesurfer.on('finished', function () {
          this.playing = false;
      });
  }

  play() {
      this.wavesurfer.play();
      this.playing = true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with `Rxjs/Subject`.

```
@Injectable()
export class AudioPlayerService {

    public wavesurfer: WaveSurfer;
    _playing: Subject<boolean> = new Subject(false);
    playing$: Observable<boolean> = _playing.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    setTrack(track): void {
        const that = this;

        // create a new instance
        this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: '#waveform'
        });

        // fire the play function
        this.wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
            that.play();
        });

        // load the waveform
        this.wavesurfer.load(track.preview_url);

        this.wavesurfer.on('finished', function () {
            this.playing.next(false);
        });
    }

    play() {
        this.wavesurfer.play();
        this.playing.next(true);
   }
}
```

In a component file, simply subscribe to `playing$`

```
@Component({})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private audioPlayerService : AudioPlayerService ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.audioPlayerService.playing$.subscribe(next => {
             if (next === false) {
                 // playing is false
             } else {
                 // playing is true
             }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm using phpstorm, and when I add `_playing: Subject<boolean> = new Subject(false);`, I get the error 'Expected 0 arguments, but got 1'. Regardless though, the page loads without errors and whether or not I put (false) there doesn't change the behavior. So I'm thinking it's a bug in phpstorm. Other than that it seems to work. I was wondering, isn't this heavy on resources? Since the component now starts listening for a change on playing$ forever, from the moment it's created. Or does it not matter?

Comment: What's your rxjs version?

Comment: Also, for your question you can (and should) unsubscribe when your component is destroyed (use `ngOnDestroy`). How many components are there to listen to it?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. My rxjs version is 5.5.6. There is only one component listening to it, but it needs to listen whenever a track is playing. The audioplayer service is never destroyed, because it's a continuous player. Does it matter (resource wise) if the player component is forever listening for the finish event? Otherwise I have to figure out a way to initiate the subscription whenever a track starts playing.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question I have come up with the idea that you need a `component` to play a track, so you can use all functionality of `wavesurfer` inside the component without any problem, it would be easy to implement and understand.

But if you insist to have a service for that. I believe that a `Sevice` should be stateless; using public variable like `playing` is not a good idea. On the other hand, consumers of your service should not access `wavesurfer` as you declared it public.

Generally, your service can raise events that notifies something happened inside the service. It is easy to implement.

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer';

@Injectable()
export class AudioPlayerService {

  private _wavesurfer: WaveSurfer;
  // public playing = false;
  public finished: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  public started: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  setTrack(track, container): void {
    const that = this;

    // create a new instance
    this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: container
    });

    // fire the play function
    this.wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
      that.play();
      that.started.emit();
    });

    // load the waveform
    this.wavesurfer.load(track.preview_url);

    this.wavesurfer.on('finished', function () {
      that.finished.emit();
    });
  }

  play() {
    this.wavesurfer.play();
    //this.playing = true;
    this.started.emit();
  }
```

I have to mention that declaring a specific event for every important action inside a service makes it   easy to understand and use.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I read your solution, it seems similar to the solution by Bunyamin. Is there a fundamental difference that is important for me to consider when making a choice between these two methods? Also, I thought it was recommended practice to put all code related to loading content in services, and code relating to displaying it in components (forgive me if that's not correct, I'm new to Angular). Or would you say that what the service is currently doing falls in the category of displaying content (since it's not making an http call or anything).

Comment: Well, what is `wavesurfer`?  Based on the description on its web site; `wavesurfer.js is a customizable audio waveform visualization, built on top of Web Audio API and HTML5 Canvas.`; it sounds like to me that it is a `service` for `HTML5`. So, all its functionality is related to the `visualization` and the service has been provided by `wavesurfer`. My concerns are all about how to design a component.